# Get the second, third order neighbors of nodes

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

l use networks to get the neighbors of  each node given the adjacency matrix.

For instance :

```
my_graph = nx.from_numpy_matrix(adjacency_matrix)
my_graph.neighbors(0)
```

returns the neighbors of the first node. In other term, the neighbors of first order

To do that for all the nodes l did the following :

```
import networkx as nx
my_graph = nx.from_numpy_matrix(adjacency_matrix)
number_nodes=len(adjacency_matrix)
for z in np.arange(number_nodes):
            indexes = [n for n in my_graph.neighbors(z)]
```

**What l'm looking for ?**

**a function that allows to get the neighbors of second, third n-ith order**

example :

**second order neighbors :**

Let say node_1 is neighbor with node_2 (first order neighbors); and node_2 is neighbor with node_4 (irst order neighbors) **then : node_1 is the second order neighbor with node_4 and first order neighbor with node_2**:

Hence the expected output is 
node_1_neighbors=[2,4]

**third order neighbors :**

Let say node_1 is neighbor with node_2 (first order neighbors); and node_2 is neighbor with node_4 (first order neighbors) and node_4 is neighbor with node_5 (first order neighbors)  **then : node_1 is the third order neighbor with node_5, the second order neighbor with node_4 and first order neighbor with node_2** :

Hence the expected output is 
node_1_neighbors=[2,4,5]

Thank you

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: l would like to get the neighbors  of a given node  with a certain hops : 2 hops, 3hops, ..., n-hops

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393842/k-th-order-neighbors-in-graph-python-networkx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [K-th order neighbors in graph - Python networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393842/k-th-order-neighbors-in-graph-python-networkx)